# How to have multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I want my command to have 3 different arguments. This is for a command where I would be able to report someone, so the third argument the reason for being reported, how would I split up the command into different arguments? Especially since the third one will have spaces between the words for the reason. My code currently:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { User, ClientUser, GuildMember, TeamMember, Message} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "USER", "REACTION"]});

module.exports = {
name: 'report',
description: "report a naughty person",

async execute(message, args, Discord, client){ 

const guild = message.guild   

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#1ed700')
    .setTitle('Report \n')
    .setDescription(`Person who reported ${message.author} \n`
        + `Channel reported in: ${message.channel}\n`
        + `Person reported: person \n` //The second argument
        + `Reason reported: Reason` ) // The third argument
     

let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
message.channel.send(`<@&${process.env.DUMMY_ROLE}>`);

}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `args` is an array, which it should be in your case, you can just access the elements you want by referring to the index number. E.G. `args[0]` would be the first argument, `args[1]` would be the second argument.

For the third argument where it can have spaces, it gets a bit more complicated. So you want to get rid of the first two arguments, you can use the `Array#splice` method.

Your code would be as simple as `const reason = args.splice(0, 2)`.